# Can't reach my ZMQ subscriber that running on a container alongside an http server, from my host machine

Tags: python, docker, zeromq

I know that there were similar questions but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. My problem is that I can't send messages from a ZMQ-publisher running on my local host, to a ZMQ-subscriber that is running inside a container that also runs an HTTP server.

I have a simple HTTP server written in python (Flask). All this HTTP server is doing is to create an instance of a ZMQ subscriber and start it(start it = make it start listening for incoming messages)

I am able to send GET messages to the HTTP server from my local host, but when the publisher sends its messages the subscriber never gets them.

**My HTTP server looks like this**:

```
import simple_subscriber

server = Flask(__name__)
import logging
from logging import getLogger
import json

'''
This is a simple http server that is responsible to get all the messages 
that the simple_subscriber received and send them as a jason array to the http client
'''
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = getLogger(__name__)
simple_subscriber_instance = None

@server.route('/')

@server.route('/startListening')
def startSubscriber():
    logger.info("starting to listen")
    global simple_subscriber_instance
    simple_subscriber_instance = simple_subscriber.SimpleSubscriber._start("tcp", "localhost", 5563, 5566, "topic_in",
                                                                           "topic_out")
    return jsonify(success=True)


@server.route('/killSubAndGetAllMessages')
def getAllMessages():
    '''
    make the simple_subscriber_instance to stop listening for incoming messages
    and get all the messages that been received until this function executes.

    :return: a json array of all the messages that been received
    '''
    all_meassages = simple_subscriber_instance.kill()
    json_list = json.dumps(all_meassages)
    logger.info("returning all messages")
    return json_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

**my subscriber:**

```
import zmq
import logging
from logging import getLogger
from typing import List, Tuple, Dict, ByteString, Callable
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class SimpleSubscriber:

    def __init__(self, context: zmq.Context, socket_in, socket_out, poller, in_topic, out_topic):

        self._logger = getLogger(__name__)
        self._context = context
        self._socket_in = socket_in
        self._socket_out = socket_out
        self._poller = poller
        self.in_topic = in_topic
        self.out_topic = out_topic

        self._isAlive = None
        self._worker = Thread(target=self._listener)
        self._worker.setName("Simple-subscriber")
        self._worker.isDaemon()
        self._messages = []

    @staticmethod
    def _init_zmq(in_protocol: str, in_ip: str, in_port: str,
                  out_port, in_topic: str, out_topic: str):

        out_addr = f"tcp://*:{out_port}"
        in_addr = f"{in_protocol}://{in_ip}:{in_port}"

        in_topic= in_topic.encode("utf-8")
        out_topic= out_topic.encode("utf-8")

        context = zmq.Context()
        socket_in = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        socket_in.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, in_topic)
        socket_in.connect(in_addr)

        socket_out = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        socket_out.bind(out_addr)

        poller = zmq.Poller()
        poller.register(socket_in)

        return context, socket_in, socket_out, poller, in_topic, out_topic

    @classmethod
    def _start(cls, in_protocol: str, in_ip: str, in_port: int, out_port: int, in_topic: str, out_topic: str):
        logger = getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("starting simple-subscriber")

        context, socket_in, socket_out, poller, in_topic, out_topic = SimpleSubscriber._init_zmq(
            in_protocol, in_ip, in_port, out_port, in_topic, out_topic)
        instance = cls(context, socket_in, socket_out, poller, in_topic, out_topic)

        instance._isAlive = True
        logger.info("starting listener function")
        instance._worker.start()

        return instance

    def kill(self):
        self._logger.info("killing worker")
        self._isAlive = False
        return self._messages

    def _listener(self):
        while self._isAlive:
            msg_map = dict(self._poller.poll(10))
            if self._socket_in in msg_map and msg_map[self._socket_in]:
                msg = self._socket_in.recv()
                self._logger.info("Received request: %s" % msg)
                self._messages.append(msg)

        self._socket_in.close()
        self._socket_out.close()
        self._logger.info("Worker is dead")
```

**and my publisher that runs on the localhost(from outside the container)**

```
import time
import zmq

out_addr = "tcp://localhost:5563"

context = zmq.Context()

socket_out = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket_out.bind(out_addr)
time.sleep(2)


for i in range(10):

    topic = b"topic_in"
    socket_out.send(topic+b" "+str(i))
```

In the case of `out_addr = "tcp://localhost:5563"` the messages are sent but never gets to the subscriber, and in the case of `out_addr = "tcp://*:5563"` I am getting this error:

```
  socket_out.bind(out_addr)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 550, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 26, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The flow is like this:

1. running the container
2. sending http://localhost:5000/startListening
3. executing the publisher script
4. sending http://localhost:5000/killSubAndGetAllMessages

I never gets the messages back (I know that step 3 doesn't reach the subscriber because it also should print the messages received)

Any ideas how can I make the messages, sent from the publisher on the local host, reach the subscriber running inside the container alongside the server?

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        software-properties-common
    RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip
    RUN python3.7 -m pip install pip
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3-distutils \
        python3-setuptools


COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r req.txt

EXPOSE 5000

EXPOSE 5563



CMD ["python3","http_server.py"]
```

and this is the command I used to run the container `docker run -p 5000:5000 -p 5563:5563 -it simple_subscriber_test`

Everything is working fine when I run it all from my local host but I need the server and the subscriber inside a container.

Comment: I have tried what you did above did you try '0.0.0.0' instead of localhost or *. Cause i wrapped my zmq in docker as well this worked for me

Comment: You are talking about the publisher or subscriber?
I think i can't put 0.0.0.0 in both server and publisher, it caused an error.
but i will try agin

Comment: Both publisher and subscriber

Comment: yes on the publisher script it raises an error 
``` 
    socket_out.bind(out_addr)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 550, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 26, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in us

```
can you show me what you did?

Comment: I can't really show you because this is company code. But i can tell you we are using a dealer router connection. I notice something strange here:

shouldn't you runned this separately?
```python
# ZMQ Server
socket_out = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket_out.bind(out_addr)
```

Comment: as in a seperate py file for publiser like a pub_server.py
for example something like this: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html

Comment: i don't think so, it works fine when all running on localhost.
my code is as the example that you sent.. or am i missing somthing?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"the subscriber never gets them."*

Given the error thrown above, ***`zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use`***
your code has struck a case, when it cannot use an address, that is occupied for any other reason (will not get free and cannot be used) or was not successfully released (ought be free, but is not) by previous runs of the same piece of code (as the code does not self-protect from an infinitely hanging `Context()`-instance I/O-thread(s) still trying to `.send()` internally Queued messages or waiting to receive next messages over the low-level (almost ZeroMQ-wire-level) protocol, even when the python session has been closed. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20LINGER) more about error-handling and preventive defensive measures so as to avoid any such hanging states and design strategies robust & resilient to all possible collisions, principally happening like this one.